# Is the style attribute deprecated in XHTML 1.1?

Tags: xhtml

is the style attribute deprecated in XHTML 1.1

Comment: What style attribute? For what tag? Do you perhaps mean the style tag?

Comment: The style *attribute* is valid for a number of elements: http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/REC-xhtml1-20000126/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd (Yes, this is 1.0, but it's the same.) Look for "%attrs" -- that should roughly equate to all the places the style *attribute* can appear.

Comment: @pst that's a good answer, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It's [not deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/present/styles.html#adef-style) in HTML 4 Strict, hence neither in XHTML 1.0 Strict, and there are [very few changes](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml11/changes.html#a_changes) from there to 1.1, which includes the feature in the [inline style module](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-modularization/DTD/xhtml-framework-1.mod).

Comment: Just 17 days after your comment W3C officially **deprecated** style attribute (not element) in XHTML 1.1 Basic

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the style attribute module is deprecated in xhtml 1.1 - for more information http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml-basic/ - use css instead.

Answer (score 0):

The style attribute was still valid in [November 2013](http://www.w3.org/TR/css-style-attr/)

Comment: OP asking if the style attribute is **deprecated** and not if it is still **valid**. Indeed it is still **valid** but is **DEPRECATED** in XHTML 1.1 Basic since 23 November 2010